# gspread update worksheet with csv batch

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

This is the code I have that is using gspread and I am trying to use the update_batch(body) method, but I'm running into some errors I don't understand. The message I'm getting is on the line sh.batch_update(body).  The error message is 'invalid json payload received unknown name SheetId'.   I'm confused about gspread. I was told that the Google drive is set up with a service account and that I should be using gspread, so I tried using the import method: gc.import_csv(spreadsheet_id,content), which works, but it also removes other sheets and it also renames the worksheet name, which I don't want.
So, I wanted to try using the update-batch(body) method instead, but I'm getting this message which I don't understand.  Thank you for any help.

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\pyscrpts\mytest.py", line 76, in main
 sh.batch_update(body)
 File "C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site- 
 packages\gspread\spreadsheet.py", line 131, in batch_update
  r = self.client.request(
File "C:\Users\ \AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site- 
packages\gspread\client.py", line 92, in request
raise APIError(response)
gspread.exceptions.APIError: {'code': 400, 'message': 'Invalid 
JSON 
payload received. Unknown name "SheetId" at 
\'requests[0].paste_data.coordinate\': Cannot find field.', 
'status': 'INVALID_ARGUMENT', 'details': [{'@type': 
'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest', 'fieldViolations': 
[{'field': 'requests[0].paste_data.coordinate', 'description': 
'Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "SheetId" at 
\'requests[0].paste_data.coordinate\': Cannot find field.'}]}]}
script:


from __future__ import print_function
from datetime import date, timedelta
import pickle
import logging
import os.path
import argparse
import sys
import socket
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import google.auth.transport.requests
import requests
import gspread
# gspread way ************
# authenticate to Google Sheets with a service account credentials 
json file
# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
SCOPES = 
['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly']
#SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']
SPREADSHEET_ID = '11G6hTgQ3nrVDQQj94BR5zeXvK453454sdfsfdsfdsd'
base = "C:/pyscrpts/"
# CREDS FILE FOR GSPREAD 
gc = gspread.service_account(filename= 'c:\pyscrpts\creds.json')

csv_file_path = base + 'updates.csv'
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'c:\pyscrpts\creds.json' 

credentials = 
service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file( 
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE,scopes=SCOPES)
def main():
#logging.basicConfig(filename='errorlog.log', filemode='w', 
format='%(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
# Creating an object
#logger=logging.getLogger(__name__)
# Setting the threshold of logger to DEBUG
#logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
creds = None

service = build('sheets', 'v4', SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE)  
sh = gc.open_by_key(SPREADSHEET_ID)
ws = sh.sheet1 
#clear worksheet 
ws.clear()

) 
content = open(csv_file_path,'r', encoding='utf-8').read()
gc.import_csv(SPREADSHEET_ID,content)

#Read csv and form request
with open(csv_file_path, 'r', encoding='UTF8') as csv_file:
    csvContents = csv_file.read()
    body = {
       'requests': [{
           'pasteData': {
               "coordinate": {
                   "SheetId": SPREADSHEET_ID,
                   "rowIndex": "0", 
                   "columnIndex": "0", 
               },
               "data": csvContents,
               "type": 'PASTE_NORMAL',
               "delimiter": ',',
           }
       }]
  }  
sh.batch_update(body)  
#requests = 
service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=SPREADSHEET_ID, 
body=body)
response = requests.execute()

if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue and your goal?

Comment: Hi, yes sorry I wasn't more clear.  I have used the gspread import to upload a csv file to a google drive, but the documentation says that it would remove other sheets as well, which I don't want to do. I read here: https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/gspread/latest/gspread.pdf that I can use the 'batch_update(body)' method, but I am getting an error message: Python type error of 'request' object is not iterable.  thanks

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I propsoed an answer. Could you please confirm it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to put CSV data to the specification sheet in a Google Spreadsheet using googleapis for python.
- You have already been able to get and put values to the Spreadsheet using Sheets API.

#### Modification points:

- In your request body, `"SheetId": SPREADSHEET_ID,` is used. In this case, the property name is `sheetId` and also, this value is required to be the sheet ID. In your script, the Spreadsheet ID is used as the sheet ID.

  - You can see about Spreadsheet ID and sheet ID at [this official document](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts).

When this is reflected in your script, how about the following modifications? For both modifications, CSV data of `csvFilePath` is put to the sheet of `sheetId`.

#### Modified script 1:

This is for googleapis of python.

```py
service = # Please use your script here.

csvFilePath = "###"  # Please set your CSV file path.
spreadsheet_id = "###"  # Please set your Spreadsheet ID
sheetId = "###"  # Please set your sheet ID.

with open(csvFilePath, "r") as f:
    csvContents = f.read()
body = {
    "requests": [
        {
            "pasteData": {
                "coordinate": {
                    "sheetId": sheetId,
                },
                "data": csvContents,
                "type": "PASTE_NORMAL",
                "delimiter": ",",
            }
        },
    ]
}
service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, body=body).execute()
```

#### Modified script 2:

This is for gspread of python.

```py
import gspread

client = gspread.oauth(###)

csvFilePath = "###"  # Please set your CSV file path.
spreadsheet_id = "###"  # Please set your Spreadsheet ID
sheetId = "###"  # Please set your sheet ID.
spreadsheet = client.open_by_key(spreadsheet_id)

with open(csvFilePath, "r") as f:
    csvContents = f.read()
body = {
    "requests": [
        {
            "pasteData": {
                "coordinate": {
                    "sheetId": sheetId,
                },
                "data": csvContents,
                "type": "PASTE_NORMAL",
                "delimiter": ",",
            }
        },
    ]
}
spreadsheet.batch_update(body)
```

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [PasteDataRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#pastedatarequest)

Comment: Thank you Tanaike,  I tried modification #2, but I had problems with 'client =gspread.oauth(##), I got a permission_denied message which I have not yet been able to figure out.

Comment: @maggiemay Thank you for replying. About `client = gspread.oauth(###)`, I apologize for this. In this case, when your client is used, please modify it with `client = gspread.service_account(filename= 'c:\pyscrpts\creds.json')`, and test it again. When your service account can access the Spreadsheet, I think that the script works.

Comment: Hi,I made the change you suggested.  I got the sheet ID from : sheetId(GID): but I get a message about 'invalid requests[0].pasteData: No grid with id: ( the id I got from the GID value)...   When I run the script afterwards, looks like the GID is different. Why is it changing?

Comment: I think it worked!  I got the sheet_id from the URL.  Thank you so much for your help.  I understand more than I did before.

Comment: thanks, I'll check the accept button.   the only issue I have now is when the file is too large, it times out, but other than that, it works. thanks so much